# How can I carry more stuff?

Tags: earthbound

I feel like I am constantly running out of room for items. Is there a way I can carry more stuff or something? I know I eventually add more characters to my party, does that give me more room for items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot increase your inventory size in Earthbound. You can utilize your sister at Escargo Express to get your inventory space back however.

If Escargo Express isn't listed on the phone directory you can call your Mom and she should give you the number. I think there is an $18 fee though.

Each additional character you get also have their own unique inventory space that is the same size as Ness's. So yes, that will also help with your inventory management.

[Escargo Express information](http://earthbound.wikia.com/wiki/Escargo_Express)

Comment: Going back to Onett and talking directly to your sister will also work.  This can be useful if you have a lot of items to store or several give/take cycles.